# Why Isn't My Insert Statement Working?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a simple PHP script in an HTML doc. The extension is `.php` but I can't figure out why it isn't inserting data into the table from the form input, my table structure is as follows:

```
UserID : int, primary key, auto increment
Firstname : varchar 
Lastname : varchar
Username : varchar
Password : varchar
DateRegistered : timestamp default - current_timestamp
DateUpdated : timestamp, attributes - on update current_timestamp default 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

My database connection credentials are correct. Please assist.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="register_form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <p>
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="last_name">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="registration_submit" value="Register">
    </p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['registration_submit']))
{

    $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($uname) || empty($pword))
    {
        echo "Required fields missing";
    }
}
else if (!empty($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
    && !empty($_POST['password']) ) 
    {
        $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $pword = $_POST['password'];
        echo "ElseIF portion reached";

        $con = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "website2");
        $query = "insert into users values(NULL,'$fname','$lname','$uname','$pword',NULL, NULL)";
        $result = $con->query($query);
        if (!$result) die("something went wrong ". $con->error);
        $result->close();
        $con->close();
        echo "<br /> User Registered";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your insert statement has no columns. Needs to be `insert into table (\`col1\`,\`col2\`) values ('val1','val2')`

Comment: I am reading this really good PHP book at the moment and in it the syntax is as follows $query = "INSERT INTO cats VALUES(NULL, 'Lion', 'Leo', 4)"; he doesn't have the column names in his query

Comment: @Rasclatt Actually, if you don't inform the columns, you have to use all of them. That's why the OP used NULL at some points.

Comment: AI does not accept NULL and make sure your others allow it. Use `''` instead for your AI column.

Comment: What's the database here? @Fred-ii- i think for Mysql it does, doesn't it?

Comment: @FirstOne Aaaaah, I did not know that! I guess that is why I'm not the "MySQL" guy at work....

Comment: ok so what should I use in the AI column?

Comment: @FirstOne far as I know, OP is trying to insert NULL into an AI'd column, where it should be AI'ing by itself. It's best to use `''` instead.

Comment: some are just too eager to submit answers. and failing in the process.

Comment: this `if (!$result) die("something went wrong ". $con->error);` should be throwing you an error; what is it?

Comment: here `values('','$fname','$lname','$uname','$pword','', '')";` that ought to make it kick into high gear. BUT... if your values contains apostrophes like `O'Neil`, that will fail you. Escape your data.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, just to make sure I understood your comment, I tested and `Auto Increment` does accept both `null` and `''`, incrementing the value (tested in `MySQL` since the OP didn't use the word `serial`).

Comment: @Fre-ii- I tried your syntax it's still not working and it's not throwing any error

Comment: @FirstOne I'm out of options with this question. OP isn't telling us what the errors are, nor do we know if whatever's being passed in the values, isn't triggering MySQL to scream out another syntax error. As in `I'm M. Larry O'Neil`. I also seen cases where `''` had to be used.

Comment: Ay @Fred-ii- I did reply and say that it isn't throwing any errors and I am not entering anything uncanny just these John Doe Johnn 123

Comment: then at this point and seeing your conditional statements, am thinking that that conditional statement could be failing. code in some hard values. If that works, then your conditional statement is failing and you need to change it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. am suspecting that `if (isset($_POST['registration_submit']))` will not fire off your 2nd conditional `else if (!empty(...`. that's about all I can see.

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii- for some reason your post appeared after yupeng's below I'm guessing network?

Comment: I honestly have no idea as to why you guys marked this post as "unhelpful" though I found the answers very helpful and my question would also be helpful to future users who come across this post- is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of your condition of `isset($_POST['registration_submit'])` is not suitable, whenever you submit your form, it meets the `if` statement, so you can't to execute the `else if` statement.

Comment: just change it like this Structure: if( !empty($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) {
      //your insert operation
}else{
 //...
}

Comment: and u sql like that:  INSERT INTO users(UserId,Firstname,Lastname,Username,PASSWORD) VALUES(NULL,'$fname','$lname','$uname','$pword')

Comment: thanks I changed the order around by now I get this error Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Website2\register.php on line 44 but my syntax is correct here it is $con = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "website2");

Comment: ensure that u have open up your mysqli extensions

Comment: Execute on the script : <?php  phpinfo(); ?> , and if u can find out the word "MysqlI Support" , that means you have open up mysqli extension

Comment: haha thanks I needed to remove the "new" keyword from the mysqli_connect statement Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (isset($_POST['registration_submit']))
{

$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$pword = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($uname) || empty($pword)) {
    echo "Required fields missing";
    exit(); //just to be safe that below else statement does not gets executed if variable is empty.
}else{
    //you have already did your argument above if data exists, so we don't need to do this argument again (!empty($_POST['data');
    $con = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "website2");
    $query = "insert into users values(NULL,'$fname','$lname','$uname','$pword',NULL, NULL)";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    if (!$result) die("something went wrong ". $con->error);
    $result->close();
    $con->close();
    echo "<br /> User Registered";
}
?>
```

Comment: SQL injection deploy...

Comment: ._. sorry and thanks :)

Comment: which in so many words, is what [I suggested here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710325/why-isnt-my-insert-statement-working#comment55192655_33710325)